# C# Getting cell value on button click for each row on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, textbox

I have gridview with buttons on it. I want the buttons on each row to get the value of the first cell in the gridview for each row. So for example the table below:
| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 |
| Happy    | Sad      | Button 1 |
| Worry    | Angry    | Button 2 |
| Excited  | Frown    | Button 3 |

When I press button 1 it will show Happy. If I press button 2 it will show Worry. So on and so forth. Need your help on how do I achieve this.

.HTML

```
<asp:gridview id="grdCreateGroup" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="grdCreateGroup_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdCreateGroup_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="admissionNo" HeaderText="Admission No." />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="fullName" HeaderText="Full Name" />
                <asp:templatefield headertext="">
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSendInvite" runat="server" Text="Send Invite" CommandName="sendInvite" /> 
                    </itemtemplate>
                </asp:templatefield>
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
```

.CS

```
protected void grdCreateGroup_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "sendInvite")
            {
                account accounta = new account();
                account accountb = new account();
                accountManager accountManager = new accountManager();
                invite invite = new invite();
                inviteManager inviteManager = new inviteManager();
                string emailAddress, admissionNo;
                bool status = true;

                emailAddress = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                accounta = accountManager.getAccInfoByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

                invite.leaderName = accounta.fullName;
                invite.groupNo = accounta.groupNo;
                //invite.recipientEmailAddress = accountb.recipientEmailAddress;

                //status = inviteManager.sendInvite(invite);

                GridViewRow Row = grdCreateGroup.Rows[0];
                Button btnSendInvite = (Button)Row.FindControl("btnSendInvite");

                if (status == true)
                {
                    divMessage.InnerHtml = invite.groupNo.ToString();

                    btnSendInvite.Text = "Invite Sent";
                    btnSendInvite.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    divMessage.InnerHtml = "Record not added in database";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' to your button and in your code behind you can get the row that raised the event.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSendInvite" runat="server" Text="Send Invite" CommandName="sendInvite"  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
```

Get the row in your code behind

```
protected void grdCreateGroup_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "sendInvite")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = grdCreateGroup.Rows[index];

                  Button b = (Button)row.FindControl("btnSendInvite");
                   b.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnSendInvite_OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  Button btn=(Button)sender;
  GridViewRow row=(GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
  string name=row.Cells[1].Text; // here you will get Name 
}
```